# How to display EmployeeID attribute from AD in userdisp.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I have a scenario here where I have to display EmployeeID in userdisp.aspx site.
Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

What does I have to do as configuration to achieve this?

Comment: I feel `sharepoint-online` tag here is irrelevant

Comment: Typically with SharePoint Server, you would have userdisp redirected to the user profile on the MySite host. Is the UPA not set up in this environment?